# How to understand this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, machine-learning

On page 179 of http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html a cost function is given as :

$$J(\theta)=-\mathbb E_{x,y{\sim}{\hat p_{data}}}\log\big(p_{model}(y|x)\big) $$

I'm accustomed to this cost function and can understand how it's implemented (mean squares cost function) : 
$$C_{MST}(W, B, S^r, E^r) = 0.5\sum\limits_j (a^L_j - E^r_j)^2$$

But $$J(\theta)=-\mathbb E_{x,y{\sim}{\hat p_{data}}}\log\big(p_{model}(y|x)\big) $$ is much more confusing for me.

Can provide high level explanation of this function so I can research the concepts involved ? Reason I ask the question in this manner is that I'm willing to perform the research but I'm not sure what to research.

Update : inferring from comment by user echzhen :
Is $p_{model}(y|x)$ the maximum likely estimate of the probability of y given x ?

Comment: Are you familiar with maximum likelihood estimator?

Comment: @echzhen I'm not familiar with the maximum likelihood estimator.